# Cron not sending email notifications

Tags: cron, mail-server

I'm finishing biulding our new server, based on 12.04 32-bit desktop version.  I've set up a few cron tasks, that are running as they're supposed.

only, I've added the MAILTO = "my_adress@ssss.gouv.qc.ca" environnement variable to be notified when tasks are running, and nothing seems to pass through.

According to logs, (and the created files) my cron tasks are running, but no mail is being sent; both /var/log/mail.log and /var/log/mail.err are empty.

Is there a mail-server automatically installed with ubuntu?  Is it what's used by the cron process to send its notifications?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a mail-server automatically installed with ubuntu?

No. Mail cron would normally send out would just get stuck in that user's local maildir and go no further.

If you want mail sent out, you need to install a mail server. Postfix is capable and secure and installing it is just an `apt-get install postfix` away.